# Converting varchar to integer on Oracle using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

In My Project Score field in Database is Varchar datatype, but it contains integer values now i need to fetch the records having score between 70 to 50. (i.e less than 70).

My Query is

```
Query count_query = 
   stmt1.query().from(selectedTable).selectCount().
   where(districtcolumn).equals(district_code).
   and(score).isNull().or(score).lessthan("70").toQuery();
```

trying to us to_num  but it not accepting. It accepts only column data types.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working properly?" - for example you don't have condition for "50" in your query

Comment: Are you asking about converting an int to a string? If so ""+intValue will work. Theres also the (arguable more correct) Integer.toString() method

Comment: @RichardTingle OP is trying to use Hibernate Criteria API to formulate a query which will do the conversion and comparison on the database side.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in a `varchar` column in the first place. You should really fix your data model instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try modify your entity like this (tested on MySQL):

```
@Formula(value = " cast(score as DECIMAL(10,0) ) ")
public long getScore()
```